# Across Cookie in Domain in Subdomain

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have two application in my work Asp.Net MVC and PHP.

PHP is my domain.

MVC is my subdomain.

php when creating the cookie looks like this -

**u%3Dxxxxxx%40xxxxxx.com%26e%3D20%2F9%2F2011+17%3A05%3A04%26c%3D4c059a53d2134867fdb64b44714f2463**

and

mvc when creating the cookie looks like this -

**u=xxxx@xxxxx.com&e=20/9/2011 20:04:12&c=8CDC334D509AED502402AAF3537DD226**

the domain in cookie = .xxx.com

But when i try to read the cookie in Mvc the cookie dont work.

```
cookie["u"]
cookie["e"]
cookie["c"]
```

What might be going wrong?

Thank you

Sorry my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that when the cookie is created (on the PHP site), the Set-Cookie header looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie: u=some_value; domain=example.com
```

Now you will be able to access this cookie from any subdomain on example.com. Inside the ASP.NET MVC application you can access it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["u"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, i'm resolve the problem, only UrlDecode. Very Thans